# Is C（E）a dual of any linear norm space?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Let $E$ is a closed bounded set of $\mathbb{R}$. Is $C（E$ a dual of any linear norm space?

Comment: What do you mean by "$E$ is a closed bounded set"? Of what? Some $\Bbb R^n$? Or do you want $E$ to be any (presumably) compact Hausdorff space? In which case you'll also want to ask that $E$ be infinite, just to rule trivialties.

Answer (score 3):

Let us assume that the question requires $E$ to be a locally compact Hausdorff space.

It is well-known that $C(E)$ with the supremum norm is a C$^*$-algebra. Sakai proved in 1971 that a C$^*$-algebra is a dual precisely when it is a von Neumann algebra. In terms of $E$, this means that it has to be compact and *extremely disconnected*: the closure of every open subset is open.

The only easy examples of this are the cases where $E$ is finite and when $E=\beta\mathbb N$ (the Stone-Čech compactification of the naturals).

In particular, $C[0,1]$ is not a dual.